# libgdx with scene2d and actor is not displaying the sprite

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I am testing out Libgdx and Scene2d. I expected this small program to display a logo, but it draws a black screen only. Any idea what am I missing?

```
public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener {
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        stage = new Stage(800, 800, false);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        MyActor actor = new MyActor();
        stage.addActor(actor);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
            stage.setViewport(800, 800, false);
    }
}


public class MyActor extends Actor {
    Sprite sprite;

    public MyActor() {
        sprite = new Sprite();
        sprite.setTexture(new Texture("data/libgdx.png"));

        setWidth(sprite.getWidth());
        setHeight(sprite.getHeight());
        setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        setX(0);
        setY(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        Color color = getColor();
        batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(sprite, getX(), getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: Force the alpha (4th parameter) to 1.0f in `batch.setColor()` and see if that helps.  I suspect the default color is all zeros.

Comment: Changed to `batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, 1.0f)`, but same result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Construct the sprite with the texture and use Gdx.file.internal:

```
sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png")));
```

Anyway, if you just want to display and act on images, you might prefer to use Image class:

```
    private Stage stage;
    private Texture texture;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
        TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);          

        com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image actor = new com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image(region);
        stage.addActor(actor);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't `setTexture(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png")));`work?

Comment: Diving into the source code, it seems that using the constructor of Sprite with a Texture also set the region of the texture, while just setting setTexture is not enough and you will manually need to use setRegion as well.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a black screen too until I explicitly set `Actor`'s height (`setHeight(height)`) and width (`setWidth(width)`) to the `Sprite`'s values.

Answer (score 0):

```
tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("happy.png"));
Image happy = new Image(tex);    
/* happy.setBounds(happy.getX(), happy.getY(), happy.getWidth(), happy.getHeight());  not needed if using full image               */    
stage.addActor(happy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely this line, in the draw method

```
batch.draw(sprite, getX(), getY());
```

The code I have seen when drawing sprites is

```
sprite.draw(batch);
```